# I have lost Symmetry when sculpting

Tags: sculpting

For some reason when I sculpt on one leg the other is not manipulated in the right place!? you can see in this pic the leg on the right I made a bump on the foot and some bulges on the lower and upper leg and you can see the other leg is off. what are some possible solutions? I included the N panel just in case that is where the problem lies[image]

Comment: I symmetry turned on or off in the tool panel in properties?

Comment: It is turned on. I think I figured it out... The rotation was not applied. So that z value being off made everything crooked on the other side